# Serial I/O Not working on DE5-Net

Tags: fpga, serial, io

I'm porting a circuit from DE0-Nano to DE5-Net.

I'm currently implementing a simple test circuit for the DE5-Net. So far I can program the user LEDs and the two Hex Displays.

However, I don't seem to be capable of doing any serial IO. My VHDL is generated, so I'll try to explain what I'm doing.

I am using an FTDI USB-RS422-WE-1800-BT cable, the FPGA connector of which I had to crimp myself. I may have made a mistake with the crimping. I don't have the tools at the moment (holidays & working from home) to test this.

The cable I mentioned before does appear to be working in the sense that it's correctly connected to `/dev/ttyUSB0`. For example:

- `lsusb` shows the cable when it's plugged in;
- `echo Hello world > /dev/ttyUSB0` returns a zero exit status and the cable's PC end connector emits light;
- `od --read-bytes=1 < /dev/ttyUSB0` doesn't throw an error but it doesn't output and it blocks.

I'm using Quartus and Ubuntu. The following provides some more detail. Some of these commands aren't needed but none of them result in an explicit error.

- I run `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 sane`;
- I run `stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw`;
- I execute 'quartus_pgm -l', which detects the FPGA;
- I run `jtagconfig`, which also detects the FPGA;
- I upload the netlist to the FPGA;
- I execute the FPGA and this results in the correct signals for the LEDs and the hex displays on the FPGA at 50MHz/9600 Baud.

My test environment simulates a continuous sequence of (10 bit data frames: one low start bit; 8 data bits; one high stop bit). Each bit signal is maintained for \$d=5*10^7/9600\$ clock cycles:
\$d\$ times 0 (start bit); \$8d\$ times 1 (constant data bits); \$d\$ times 1 (stop bit).
Im sending the start/data/stop bits to Pin AE17, while maintaining a low signal on Pins AF17 and AF16, and maintaining a high signal on Pin AG14.

If someone sees an obvious mistake or has a suggestion for a diagnostic test, please let me know.

Comment: Does loopback work?

Comment: @Hearth I have very little experience with/knowledge about this kind of "stuff" (no elec/eng background). IIUC you need some hardware for this and I don't have access to it at the moment.

Comment: Loopback is something you can implement on your FPGA, but I'm pretty sure you can also do it just by shorting Tx to Rx.

Comment: Any reason why you dont have a DMM yet?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I don't understand the yet in your question. I am trying to solve a problem without the tools an expert would have used/knows how to use.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks. I may have a look at that.

Comment: @Joey A digital multimeter (DMM) is something that anyone working on electronics should try to get as soon as possible, expert or beginner. That's why Tony said "yet".

Comment: @Hearth Thanks. I understood the underlying meaning of the question/comment. I'm not working in electronics:-)

Comment: @Joey I'd consider working with an FPGA to count! It wouldn't be a bad idea to get even a cheap $5 hardware-store meter.

Comment: @Hearth Thanks. Will have a look at it. Of course then I'd have to learn how to use.

Comment: @Joey Don't worry, they're very easy. Just don't short things out with the current mode!

Comment: It's unclear that an "RS422" cable is going to be compatible with this usage.  Anyway, you need to start by determining that it is even electrically and logically compatible with your need, then switching to a terminal program, then testing loopback between the pins of the cable, then testing loopback (but not actual logic) within the FPGA.  Then you can move on to looking at data formats, baud rates, etc both in theory and using either the FPGA tool's ability to compile in a logic analyzer or using a budget USB-based one outside. These are tasks *you* need to do before others can really help.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am only following instructions given by somebody who advised me the cable was needed. Anyway, I appreciate your comment I should know what I'm doing (which I don't). I've already asked help from somebody in the flesh but they have to self-isolate for a few days before they can do the things which you're suggesting.

Comment: Call them on the phone or video chat and work through it together.